# What's the meaning of the `an entire hard disk drive`?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, imagex

When I read the definition of [ImageX](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/ImageX):

> ImageX is a command-line tool that allows an administrator to capture an image of an entire hard disk drive and its files and folders in a single Windows Imaging Format (WIM) file.

I can understand the `its files and folders`, but I don't know the `an entire hard disk drive`, what's the meaning of it?

---

**Edit-01**

We know the `an entire hard disk drive` means an entire physical disk with its contents and filesystem in it.

But how to understand `ImageX` capture `an entire hard disk drive` and xxx?

How can `ImageX` can capture a `an entire hard disk drive`? is it mean `ImageX` only capture the contents and filesystem of `an entire hard disk drive`?

Or contain other information?

Comment: In this context it means "a partition" or "a filesystem" .

Comment: do you mean a partition with the filesystem in it?

Comment: can't it be multi partitions of a physical disk, right ? only can be one partition of a disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that the description is confusing.

On the one hand it contains a link to
[image](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/disk-image),
and qualifies this with the mention of
[entire hard disk drive](https://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/hard-disk-drive),
then in the same sentence also talks about
files and folders, which belong inside one or more file-systems inside
one or more partitions.

The clue comes from the fact that its result is stored in a
[Windows Imaging Format (WIM) file](https://searchenterprisedesktop.techtarget.com/definition/Windows-Imaging-Format-WIM),
which it defines as:

> WIM is file-based rather than sector-based, allowing a single file package to contain all of the package contents, deduplicate multiple instances of the same components, and also boot and install faster on a wider range of disk hardware. In addition, a single WIM file can contain multiple disk images, allowing users to install some or all of the images depending on what is being distributed. For example, a single WIM file may be created with several different versions of Windows 7. WIM also supports spanning, so large WIM files can be broken into two or more parts denoted with an .SWM extension.

Therefore my conclusion is that ImageX can only capture one partition with
its files, and probably not even the
[Master File Table (MFT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Master_File_Table),
and certainly not the partition table or multiple partitions.
A single WIM file can contain images of multiple partitions, each separate,
but not of an entire hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

It means a complete *physical* drive, as opposed to just individual partitions which themselves contain file systems upon which a user stores files.

You will usually store files within a *partition* rather than an actual *drive*. That we call it the "C drive" is a simplification, it is actually the "partition that has been allocated the drive letter C".

They are saying that they will copy *all* the information on a drive, including partition boundaries, boot sectors and potentially the Host Protected Area (HPA).

Comment: Thanks your response, can you take a look at my **Edit-01**?

Comment: @Mokubai: Unfortunately, one cannot store a disk-image in a WIM file (*Windows* image and not *disk* image), but only partition *contents* (meaning only files). I think that the above description of ImageX is a big mess, using terms the writer didn't understand. Your above text is correct, just not for ImageX.

Comment: @harrymc I am *technically correct. The best kind of correct*.

Comment: That's a good way of resolving the issue.